# jQuery ajax request and html only display one time the data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

good day!

I have a problem, this is when I click on my button for ajax request this works perfectly and display the data on my select item but, when I click again on the button for ajax request, this give the data (this is correct) but on my select item this show again the data so, I have the same data two times, how can I solve this? I´m new into JS and this is for my school project haha, so Thank u so much if u can help me! <3

this is my js code

```
  $("#hola").click( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/api/check-estudio/',
    data: {},
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: true,
    success: function(data) {
      for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        console.log(data[i]);
        var optionHTML = '<option>' + data[i].name + '</option>';
        $(".selectEstudio").append(optionHTML);
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
      console.log(xhr, resp, text);
    }
  });
```

When I click first time work perfectly and display my data on my select box and show the options.
[image: Picture 1]

When I close de modal and Click again the button for show modal and ajax request, display two times the same info.
[image]

THANK U FOR YOUR TIME! <3

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/empty/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `.append()` use `.html()` along with a bit code enhancement:-

```
var optionHTML =''; // define variable
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    optionHTML += '<option>' + data[i].name + '</option>'; // add all options
}
$(".selectEstudio").html(optionHTML); // append in last not inside loop one-by-one
```

Or you can first [empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) select-box and then add again:-

```
var optionHTML ='';
 $(".selectEstudio").empty();
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    optionHTML += '<option>' + data[i].name + '</option>';
}
$(".selectEstudio").html(optionHTML);
```

Comment: OMG!, so simple?, now is working correctly! Thank u so much!

Comment: @MiguelToledano  glad to help you :):)

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie - I am gettiing an HTML data as Ajax callback from Django view.  (**PS.** HTML data looks like : <table border="1" class="dataframe [x_data, sortable]" id="selFrtTblHdr">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>mat_frt_grp</th>
      <th>from_date</th>
      <th>to_date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>MS</td>
      <td>2004-04-01</td>
      <td>2005-03-31</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
**How could I render the HTML data on the page using jQuery?**

Answer (score 2):

It's because of you are appending same data into `select` over and over again. Instead of doing that, you can generate the `option` tags first then append it to `select`'s innerhtml once for every request like that :

```
var optionsArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var optionElement = $('<option>', '</option>');
    optionElement.text(data[i]);
    optionsArray.push(optionElement);
}

$(".selectEstudio").append(optionsArray);
```

For readability i can say that avoid hard-coding html tags with in strings. Just create them with jQuery's selector like this : `$('<option>', '</option>')`. This approach gives you chance of extending element's attributes with more elegant and readable way, and there is no need for `for` loop here since you are just creating bunch of element every time. Just use `map` function and assign elements to array explicitly like this :

```
var optionsArray = data.map(function(current) {
    var optionElement = $('<option>', '</option>');
    optionElement.text(current);
    return optionElement;
});

$(".selectEstudio").append(optionsArray);
```

It's much readable right ?